# lost all my admin privileges in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, administrator, task-manager, privileges

Today I suddenly encountered a problem, the last thing I remember i did before the problem occurred was that I was installing a game from the Steam, the game asked to install Nvidea Physx, after that, the current problems happened (without any error showing up):

- Can't see task manager when i right click my task bar or even after pressing CTRL+ALT+Del.
- I managed to activate task manager from gpedit.msc but it gets disabled automatically.
- Can't access the regedit.exe (says deactivated by administrator).
- The CPU is always higher than 65%. Random processes (even like Firefox, adobe reader..) takes around 50%, when i kill it, another random process takes 50%..
- I tried scanning my PC (and I'm still doing it again) with Malwarebytes and have Quarantined many suspicious things but all the problems before remained.

(notice that I'm doing all this using my only administrator account which was working fine 4 hours ago).

- I activated the default Administrator account (which is hidden by default) but the same problems are happening even with it.
- I tried doing a system restore but it showed an error after the system gets restarted (an error with a 80070005 error code which looked unhelpful to me).
- Also the SFC scannow terminated without any problem.

I'm really clueless now, it looks like I have lost all my administrator privileges in a glimpse.

*Example of the problems Malwarebytes has found:*
[image: Example of the problems Malwarebytes has found]

Comment: @DavidPostill, thanks for the link, but it could have been more helpful if you explained to me or helped me understand the problem that I'm experiencing better than send me to another random thread.

Comment: First;  The installation of the game has nothing to do with your problems unless we are dealing with a hardware failure.  Second none of what you describe mean you lost your administrator privileges.  If you can escalate a process then you have Administrator permissions.  So try use SFC to verify your windows installation isn't corrupt.

Comment: It's **not** a random thread. It is good advice on how to get rid of virus/malware/... which is clearly what you have ("I tried scanning my PC (and I'm still doing it again) with Malwarebytes and have Quarantined many suspicious things but all the problems before remained.")

Comment: Without knowing **what** virus you have we cannot give more explicite advice. We are clueless too without more information.

Comment: @Ramhound installing the game could have installed a virus with it. We don't have enough info to tell...

Comment: What "suspicious things" have been quarantined? What was the exact "80070005" error message? Please [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/836683/edit) your question to include this info. Help us to help you...

Comment: i'll try to collect more info and edit the question in few minutes, I have also tried SFC but nothing was wrong.

Comment: @DavidPostill - I can say without a shadow of a doubt, with 99.99999% certainty that a Steam game did not have a virus contained within it.  So the two events are entirely separate from his problems.  He likely already was infected.  What is being detected is from an infection spread from within a browser anyways.

Comment: @TechSupport - Please provide us the console output after the SFC command was issued.

Comment: Sorry i closed the console, but it said that the scan terminated (100%) and no problem was found.